# validating regex input fields

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I get an alert telling me the address needs to contain only alpha numeric chars..

What i have for the regex is `/^\w+$/`

so when i put `123 Lane Street`

it gives me that error. Any ideas why it's doing this?

```
 if (address == ""){
                  errors += "please enter a address \n";
                } else { 
                    addressRE = /^\w+$/;
                    if (address.match(addressRE)){
                      //console.log("address match");
                      //do nothing.
                    } else {
                      //console.log("address not a match");
                      errors += "Address should only contain alphanumeric characters \n";
                    } // end if
                }
```

Comment: yes, it would show the error because the address contain spaces.

Comment: In addition, http://rubular.com/ is a quick and interactive way to learn regex. Try it out with the addresses above.
you can use this expression also :^[a-zA-Z\d\s]*

Comment: @zx81 i can't bud. Don't have enough rep points :'(

Comment: ah, forgot all about that. Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space character in `123 Lane` is not considered to be alphanumeric.

You need `/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i`

The `i` turns on case-insensitive matching.

In JS:

```
if (/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/i.test(yourString)) {
    // It matches!
} else {
    // Nah, no match...
}
```

Comment: I think your answer matches a single character.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You're totally right, I forgot the `+`. I often do that. Thanks a lot. :)